# Confused about class inheritance in Ruby with multiple references to self

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm attempting to deconstruct a ruby gem to get a better understanding of Oop in ruby. In most cases I can really see the benefit of inheritance and using modules as name spaces etc. In some cases, though. I'm not sure I get the added benefit, I'm thinking maybe at scale there are benefits I cannot understand on my local machine. For instance....

This code.

```
module TestInheritance
    @testVariable = ""

    def self.configure
        yield @testVariable
    end
end
```

And this code

```
module TestInheritance2
    @testVariable = ""

    class << self
        attr_accessor :testVariable
    end

    def self.configure
        yield self.testVariable
    end
end
```

Does exactly the same thing. In TestInheritance2 an unamed class inherits self, which in this case is the entire module and then makes the test variable accessible outside the class. The configuration block works just fine without this step why add this to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of this question is very limited; without more of a use case, there is no reason to prefer the second block of code over the first. However, there is one major difference, which could come into play in a more fully-formed use case:

In the first block of code, the value of `testVariable` is available only to methods on the `TestInheritance` object.

In the second block of code, the value of `testVariable` is exposed to other callers via the method `TestInheritance2.testVariable`.

Here is another more verbose, and yet perhaps clearer way to create the getter and setter methods (which will behave the same as in the second block of code):

```
module TestInheritance2
  @testVariable = ""

  def self.testVariable
    return @testVariable
  end

  def self.testVariable=(value)
    @testVariable = value
  end
end
```